# Custom Annotations not showing error if we pass wrong value in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying create an custom annotation to replace enums in my android application. I have followed Java docs and documentation https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html#enum-annotations provided by Android created an annotation as below.

But studio was not showing any error when I try to set a value which are defined in "Intdef".

Thanks in Advance!

```
    public static final int NONE = 0;
    public static final int FRONT_CAMERA = 1;
    public static final int BACK_CAMERA = 2;
    public static final int IMAGE_CAPTURE_INTENT = 3;
    public static final int VIDEO_CAPTURE_INTENT = 4;

    @Retention(SOURCE)
    @IntDef({NONE, FRONT_CAMERA, BACK_CAMERA, IMAGE_CAPTURE_INTENT, VIDEO_CAPTURE_INTENT})
    @interface CaptureType {}


    private int captureType;

    public void setCaptureType(@CaptureType int captureType){
        this.captureType = captureType;
    }

    public @CaptureType int getCaptureType() {
        return captureType;
    }
    //When I set value using setCapture()


    setCapture(5)// not showing error.
```